# Change font style of label with Ajax editor control asp dot net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i have following asp control on my page

1. Label
2. Textbox with ajax editor control

I have javascript which check keyup event of textbox ajax editor control and assign the value to label. But strange thing is, its not assigning the font color, size of textbox to label.

here is the script and htmll

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
         var htmlEditorBox = $('.ajax__html_editor_extender_texteditor');
         htmlEditorBox.keyup(function () {
             document.getElementById('<%=Label2.ClientID%>').innerHTML = this.textContent;
            <%-- document.getElementById('<%=Label2.ClientID%>').style.color = this.textColor.innerHTML;--%>

         });
     });
</script>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="300" Height="200">     </asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender runat="server" BehaviorID="TextBox1_HtmlEditorExtender" TargetControlID="TextBox1" ID="TextBox1_HtmlEditorExtender" EnableSanitization="False"></ajaxToolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

I want to assign textbox ajax control editor formatting to label as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer

```
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(function () {
        var htmlEditorBox = $('.ajax__html_editor_extender_texteditor');
        htmlEditorBox.keyup(function () {
            document.getElementById('lblContents').innerHTML = $('.ajax__html_editor_extender_texteditor').html();
        });
    });
</script>
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEditor" CssClass="Editor" runat="server" Width="300" Height="200" />
<asp:HtmlEditorExtender ID="HtmlEditorExtender1" runat="server"          TargetControlID="txtEditor"
    EnableSanitization="false">
</asp:HtmlEditorExtender>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
<br />
Entered Text:
<asp:Label ID="lblContents" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the code below inside the `keyup` event. I've done it on my side and it works just fine:

```
var color = $(this).css('color');
var fontSize = $(this).css('font-size');

alert(color + "," + fontSize);

document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').style.color = color;
document.getElementById('<%=Label1.ClientID%>').style.fontSize = fontSize;
```

Comment: i have added the above code in my in keyup function but it does not work

Comment: debug it using the Chrome browser console and see what the values of color and fontSize variables are.Google how to debug javascript in Chrome.

Comment: i debug it, unfortunately the code this piece of code var color = $(this).css('color');
var fontSize = $(this).css('font-size');

alert(color + "," + fontSize); not fetching the value ajax editor control but all the time showing font size 14 px